# Enforce Edit Mode Format in Custom Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I created a custom html helper for dates where amongst other things I am enforcing a format. Interestingly when I deployed to server I discovered that the format is not enforced without the following metadata attribute:

```
DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)
```

I tried to replicate the same functionality within the helper as follow:

```
(html.ViewData.ModelMetadata as CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadata).EditFormatString = format;
(html.ViewData.ModelMetadata as CachedDataAnnotationsModelMetadata).DisplayFormatString = format;
var attributes = CreateDateAttributes(format, htmlAttributes);
return html.TextBoxFor(expression, format, attributes);
```

I am casting to CachedDataAnnotionsModelMetadata as it seemed to be the only way to trigger the HasNonDefaultEditFormat flag, which actually didn't help at all.

This was kind of a pressing issue, so I simply added the attribute with the single property ApplyFormatInEditMode for the time being, but a more convenient solution would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no reason you need to do that. You can simply read the format from the `ModelMetadata` in your extension method - `ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);` and then `html.TextBoxFor(expression, metaData.DisplayFormatString)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry somehow missed this response and used the workaround temporarily. this doesn't not work, this is basically what I am doing right now.